# Google sheet(google-spreadsheet) wrapper for javascript Error 500 internal error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wanted to ask for some help.
I used a great [google-spreadsheet library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) for a few months to write data in Google Sheets.
All worked excellently until last week.
Somehow, I don't know what happened (I didn't change my code), but now when I try to use this library I get an error (the same error occurs also if I use Python, another library).
I tried to remove some of the sheets, and it works. To continue, I would like to know if someone encountered this issue or how I can debug it. It is probably some data that caused the error.

This is the error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I have attached the code (although I'm almost sure it's not related to the code since other python library for Google Sheets causes the same error):

AddToGoogleSheet.js

```js
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
async function ReadDate(sheetNum) {
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(require("./keys.json"));
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[sheetNum];
  const rows = await sheet.getRows();
  console.log(rows.length);
}

module.exports = {
  addrowtosheet,
  ReadDate
};
```

app.js

```js
let sheetservice = require("./Sheets/AddToGoogleSheet");
//let os = require('os');
sheetservice.ReadDate(0)
```

Comment: Please provide more information and the code that leads to this error.

Comment: Hi, I added the code the main post

Comment: I cannot help you with this, since I do not know this library, but I added the `google-sheets-api` tag to your question in order to increase visibility.

Comment: Thank you very much...

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. You should describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, including the spreadsheet size (how many sheets, the size of each sheet data range). The .gs code should be complete: Don't copy-paste everything, create a function that reproduces the error with the minimal code lines necessary. (This question was bumped  due to a recent answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think your file is too big/ has too many rows/data.
I encountered this issue and tried with a lighter sheet and it worked.